# Joining and comparing values of one df with first value of second df and then cumulative comparison

Tags: python, pandas, merge, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes according to dates such as:
df1

```
id       date      time      sum
abc   15/03/2020  01:00:00    15
abc   15/03/2020  02:00:00    25
abc   15/03/2020  04:00:00    10
xyz   15/03/2020  12:00:00    30
xyz   15/03/2020  03:00:00    20
```

df2

```
id        date      sum_last   
abc    14/03/2020    10            
xyz    14/03/2020    20
```

i want to create a column of Flag in df1 by comparing the values of sum column if value of a sum row is greater than previous sum row then flag is 1 or else its 0 but for the first row of sum column value 15 it will not be Nan,,it will be compared with the value of df2 sum value as it is of same id for one date lesser i.e 14th march 2020.So the output will be:

```
id       date      time      sum   Flag 
abc   15/03/2020  01:00:00    15   1     
abc   15/03/2020  02:00:00    25   1     
abc   15/03/2020  04:00:00    10   0     
xyz   15/03/2020  12:00:00    30   1     
xyz   15/03/2020  03:00:00    20   0
```

Can anyone help me to join these two dfs and get exact result by comparing the value of df2 with df1's sum columns's 1st value according to id column.Thanks in advance

Comment: It is always compared by previous Dates like in question sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df1)
    id        date      time  sum  sum1
0  abc  15/03/2020  01:00:00   15    10
1  abc  15/03/2020  02:00:00   25    10
2  abc  15/03/2020  04:00:00   10    10
3  xyz  15/03/2020  12:00:00   30    10
4  xyz  15/03/2020  03:00:00   20    10

print (df2)
    id        date  sum  sum1
0  abc  15/03/2020   10     0
1  xyz  14/03/2020   20   100
```

---

```
#columns for processing
cols = ['sum','sum1']
#columnsnames in df2
new = [x + '_last' for x in cols]
#dictionary for rename for match with df1.columns
d = dict(zip(new, cols))
print (d)

#set id to index
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df2 = df2.set_index('id')

#shifting per id and first NaN repalced by df2
df = df1.groupby('id')[cols].shift().fillna(df2.rename(columns=d)[cols])
print (df)
      sum   sum1
id              
abc  10.0    0.0
abc  15.0   10.0
abc  25.0   10.0
xyz  20.0  100.0
xyz  30.0   10.0
```

---

```
#comapred and added to df1
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df1[cols].gt(df[cols]).astype(int).add_prefix('flag_')], axis=1)
print (df1)
           date      time  sum  sum1  flag_sum  flag_sum1
id                                                       
abc  15/03/2020  01:00:00   15    10         1          1
abc  15/03/2020  02:00:00   25    10         1          0
abc  15/03/2020  04:00:00   10    10         0          0
xyz  15/03/2020  12:00:00   30    10         1          0
xyz  15/03/2020  03:00:00   20    10         0          0
```

Comment: yeah the df2 is for previous date so its not necessary to join both dfs on id and date,,we can simply merge them on id

Comment: actually we dont need to change the date of df2..we just have to merge it wid df1 on id..so can you tell me precisely the simpler way to apply this

Comment: `for the first row of sum column value 15 it will not be Nan,,it will be compared with the value of df2 sum value as it is of same id for one date lesser i.e 14th march 2020.` - so it means no compare by previous dates? Then not understand.

Comment: yes but it will be made sure that df2 will have one day prior data so we can ignore date on that matter

Comment: @naina - OK, so dates are not important and not necessary match by them? Only by `id` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233402/discussion-between-naina-and-jezrael).

Comment: i got one more issue in this..I am editing this question for help.Please reply

Comment: @naina - Maybe the best is post new question ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68016966/joining-and-comparing-values-of-one-df-with-first-value-of-another-pandas

Comment: You have helped me in flag column..Can you please help me in other two also

Comment: I have posted new question for this